# Website scraping not working properly for Medics

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I developed this script here to collect information from surgeons (public source) and put it in a spreadsheet.

The script automates the extraction of plastic surgeon information from a website.
Cycles through a list of states.
Select a state on the website form and perform a search.
It collects the information of the surgeons found on each page and goes to the next page (if any).
Store data in an Excel file.
Adjusts column width in Excel file for better readability.
Repeat the process for all states and end the script.
The problem is that it is giving a small error and I am not finding where.

It starts by scanning and collecting data from the first site (it doesn't have a forward button). So far so good. Then it switches to the next state normally and continues collecting data. Then the problem comes here, when it finishes collecting the data from this first page of the next state, it advances to the next page but does not collect the data from the next one. And besides, it hangs in it and returns to the IDE screen with this error:

**info_content = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'surgeon-info'))).text**

I need it to keep collecting data from all pages. I've been trying to find where the error is for 5 hours now.

If anyone can help me I'd be very grateful. Here's the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re
import time
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "http://www2.cirurgiaplastica.org.br/encontre-um-cirurgiao/#busca-cirurgiao"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

estados = ["AC", "AL", "AP", "AM", "BA", "CE", "DF", "ES", "GO", "MA", "MT", "MS", "MG", "PA", "PB", "PR", "PE", "PI", "RJ", "RN", "RS", "RO", "RR", "SC", "SP", "SE", "TO"]

try:
    data = pd.read_excel("cirurgioes.xlsx")
except FileNotFoundError:
    data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Nome", "Email", "Cidade/Estado", "CRM", "Telefone", "Endereço"])

for estado in estados:

    select_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'cirurgiao_uf')
    select_element.click()
    select_state = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//option[@value="{estado}"]')
    select_state.click()

    search_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'cirurgiao_submit')
    search_button.click()

    time.sleep(2)

    count = 0
    while True:
        num_links = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@href="#0"]'))

        for i in range(num_links):
            links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@href="#0"]')
            links[i].click()
            time.sleep(2)

            name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'h3'))).text
            info_content = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'cirurgiao-info'))).text

            info_lines = info_content.split('\n')

            email = info_lines[3]
            state = info_lines[1]
            crm = ""
            phone = ""
            address = ""

            for line in info_lines[4:]:
                if re.match(r'^\d+\.?\d*\/[A-Z]{2}$', line):
                    crm = line
                elif line.startswith(("Rua ", "Avenida ", "RUA ", "AVENIDA ")):
                    address = line
                elif line.startswith("Comercial: (55) "):
                    phone = line.replace("Comercial: (55) ", "")

            data = data.append({"Nome": name, "Email": email, "Cidade/Estado": state, "CRM": crm, "Telefone": phone, "Endereço": address}, ignore_index=True)
            count += 1

            if count % 10 == 0:
                data.to_excel("cirurgioes.xlsx", index=False)

            body = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body')
            body.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
            time.sleep(2)

        next_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.cirurgiao-pagination-link')
        if len(next_buttons) == 0:
            break
        next_button = next_buttons[-1]
        next_button.click()
        time.sleep(4)

    print(f"Estado {estado} salvo com sucesso.")
    data.to_excel("cirurgioes.xlsx", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use their Ajax API to get the information. It seems that one Ajax call loads all the doctors from the state:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

home_url = 'http://www2.cirurgiaplastica.org.br/encontre-um-cirurgiao/#busca-cirurgiao'
api_url = 'https://icase.sbcp.itarget.com.br/api/localiza-profissional/?format=json&nome=&categoria_profissional_id=&uf_descricao={state}&pag=1'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(home_url).content, 'html.parser')
states = [o['value'] for o in soup.select('#cirurgiao_uf option')[1:]]

all_data = []
for s in states:
    print(f'State {s}...')
    all_data.extend(requests.get(api_url.format(state=s), headers=headers).json()['data'])

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)

m = df['telefone'].isna()
df['telefone'] = df.loc[~m, 'telefone'].apply(json.loads)
df = df.explode('telefone')
df['telefone'] = df['telefone'].str['fone']

print(df.head())
```

This prints the df with the data.

Comment: the info was made in js, i didnt understand what you did

Comment: @LucasFernandes When you select the state and click search, the page makes request to the server and server responds with the medic data in Json format. This script simulates that.

Comment: Nice idea! Do you know why when i click in your link i dont get the "Endereço(Address)" field on json?

Comment: @LucasFernandes That data is loaded from another request from URL `https://icase.sbcp.itarget.com.br/api/endereco?token=4b545c6f63d3d630a3d8f6892a9fd928&tipo=C&pessoa_id=<PESSOA_ID>`. Substitute `<PESSOA_ID>` for values from the `pessoa_id` column from dataframe.

Comment: Thanks bro, i need think more outside the box lol